# Check off which password to copy

Tags: python, tkinter, passwords

So i am using Tkinter and SQLite to create a simple GUI program where i can enter details, automatically get safe passwords, retrieve data that i have stored and delete data i have stored.

When i add a user (or an account of mine) to the database, i put in the username i have chosen, the platform and the password gets automatically generated. When i retrieve the data i have stored, i have an "copy password" button, because it is not possible to copy from the Tkinter window.
My problem now is, when i add two users on the same website (which is of course a realistic situation) and then want to retrieve the data, two users pop up (which is fine), but the "copy password" button only copies the password of the last user that pops up.

Any ideas??

So i have an idea of using check-boxes, so that i can check off which password i want to copy, but it is hard for me to come up with the code.

Here is the code for how i find users in the first place:

```
def find_detalis():
    entered_platform = platform_entry.get().lower()

    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM MyUsers WHERE platform=?', (entered_platform,))
    users = cursor.fetchall()

    if users:
        info_message = "Users Found:\n"
        for user in users:
            decrypted_username = decrypt_data(user[1], key)
            decrypted_password = decrypt_data(user[2], key)
            platform = user[3]
            info_message += f"\nUsername: {decrypted_username}\nPassword: {decrypted_password}\nPlatform: {platform}\n{'='*20}"

        info_box_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
        info_box_window.geometry("320x390+620+300")
        info_box_window.title("User found")

        label = tk.Label(info_box_window, text=info_message)
        label.pack(pady=10)

        def copy_to_clipboard():
            pyperclip.copy(decrypted_password)

        copy_info_button = tk.Button(info_box_window, text="Copy password to clipboard", command=copy_to_clipboard)
        copy_info_button.pack(pady=10)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

****Description:****
I also made a program in which I needed to import and copy a key and use it elsewhere in the Operating System.
In that situation I found a library named [pyperclip](https://github.com/asweigart/pyperclip).

****Usage:****

I used pyperclip to copy the test inside of a entry box in my program, in-order to perform that I used the following code:

```
pyperclip.copy(entrybox_2.get('0,0', 'end')
# Where entrybox_2 is an entrybox widget of tkinter
```

****Example:****
So if U want to utilize pyperclips functionality:

```
import pyperclip

pyperclip.copy()
# Inside of the .copy() function add .get() function to retrive the password string
```

****Additional Info:****
As a member of the stackoverflow community try to be descriptive and also add some example code with your issue so that the issue can be solved easily.

Comment: Okay thank you. But i already use the pypaperclip library. The problem is when two users are found and i want to copy the password, only the last one that is found is copied

Comment: There are multiple methods through which the action you want can be achieved but that would require a code example. Example: The snippet of how are you finding the existence of the users.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Radiobutton` for each record fetched and copy the selected one to clipboard:

```py
def find_details():
    entered_platform = platform_entry.get().lower()

    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM MyUsers WHERE platform=?', (entered_platform,))
    users = cursor.fetchall()

    if users:
        info_box_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
        info_box_window.geometry("320x390+620+300")
        info_box_window.title("User found")

        tk.Label(info_box_window, text="Users Found:").pack()

        passwd_var = tk.StringVar() # tkinter variable for radio buttons
        for user in users:
            decrypted_username = decrypt_data(user[1], key)
            decrypted_password = decrypt_data(user[2], key)
            platform = user[3]
            # create radiobutton for this record
            info_message = f"Username: {decrypted_username}\nPassword: {decrypted_password}\nPlatform: {platform}\n{'='*20}"
            tk.Radiobutton(info_box_window, text=info_message, justify="left",
                           variable=passwd_var, value=decrypted_password).pack()

        passwd_var.set(decrypted_password) # select the last one initially

        def copy_to_clipboard():
            password = passwd_var.get()
            print(password)
            pyperclip.copy(password)

        copy_info_button = tk.Button(info_box_window, text="Copy password to clipboard", command=copy_to_clipboard)
        copy_info_button.pack(pady=10)
```